# Use of Sanov's Theorem, Optimisation Problem

Tags: probability, optimization, discrete-optimization, large-deviation-theory

Suppose we roll a die 10000 times, and observe that the mean is 3.8. How many sixes did we roll?

I know that this is an application of Sanov's theorem for finite alphabets - if the sample mean of a sequence of iid random variables, $L_n$ is close to $x$, then the empirical distribution is close to the probability measure $\nu$ that has the minimum relative entropy with respect to the probability measure of the sequence $L_n$.

In this case, my sample space is $A = \lbrace 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6 \rbrace$, and I have that $\mu (a) = \frac{1}{6} \quad \forall \, a \in A $.

The relative entropy between two probability measures is
$$ H(\nu \shortmid \mu) = \sum_{a \in A} \nu(a) \log \frac{\nu(a)}{\mu(a)}$$

So my problem reduces to one of minimising 
$$\sum_{i=1}^6 \nu(i) \log \left(\frac{\nu(i)}{\frac{1}{6}}\right)$$ subject to $$\sum_{i=1}^6 i\nu(i) = 3.8, \quad \sum_{i=1}^6 \nu(i) = 1$$
I don't know how to proceed with this optimisation problem - I have tried to use Lagrange multipliers, but I get a distribution whose sum is greater than 1.

Any hints on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I've done this right, but here's my attempt at resolving this:

To optimize
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1} ^6 \nu(i) \log   \left(\frac{\nu(i)}{\frac{1}{6}} \right)
\end{equation}
Constrained with:
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{i=1} ^6 i \nu(i) &=& \mu\\\sum_{i=1} ^6 \nu(i) &=& 1
\end{eqnarray}

Using method of Lagrange Multipliers we may rewrite this as:
\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{i=1} ^6 \nu(i) \log   \left(\frac{\nu(i)}{\frac{1}{6}} \right)+\alpha( \sum_{i=1} ^6 \nu(i)-1)+\beta(\sum_{i=1} ^6 i \nu(i) - \mu)
\end{eqnarray}
Yielding:
\begin{eqnarray}
\log(\nu(i))+\log(6)+1+\alpha+i \beta&=&0 \rightarrow \nu(i)=\tilde{\alpha}e^{-i\beta}\\
 \sum_{i=1} ^6 \nu(i) &=& 1 \rightarrow \tilde{\alpha} = \sum_{i=1} ^6 e^{-i \beta}\\ \sum_{i=1} ^6 i \nu(i) &=& \mu \rightarrow \{\beta\in\mathbb{R}:\sum_{i=1} ^6 (i-\mu)e^{-i\beta}=0\}
\end{eqnarray}
The $\tilde{\alpha}$ condition gives normalization. The $\beta$ condition enforces the average.

Testing for reasonable values $\mu=3.5$ is solved for $\beta=0$.

Using a numerical solver for $\mu=3.7$ gives $\beta = -0.1035$ and $\tilde{\alpha}=0.114204$. This is expected as a higher than expected average can only come about by making $\beta < 0$.

$\nu(i) = .114205e^{i\cdot 0.1035}$

Comment: Thanks Kitter. However, the probabilities ($\nu(i)$) do not add up to one - they add up to about 2.1 or so - so there is a problem somewhere with your solution.

Comment: Simple arithmetic error.

Comment: @KitterCatter: We are supposed to take $\mu=3.8$, no? Any reason why you took $\mu=3.7$?

Comment: Going to be honest that I don't remember exactly as it has been a while since I answered this.

If I had to hazard a guess it was to give an example solution that was close but not exact so the asker could fill in the details.